# SNMP Client no Responding on Debian10

Tags: debian, snmp

I setup SNMP client on a Debian10 machine with minimal configurations, but the SNMP server cound't receive the SNMP from the client.

The `snmpd.conf` on client:

```
com2sec my-sec default abc123
group   my-grp        v2c          prtg-sec
view    my-view    included   .1
access  my-grp     ""     any             noauth          exact   prtg-view      none    none
```

Iptables is empty on client, and fail2ban on the client is not blocking the server IP.

Running **snmpwalk** on the client with local IP works fine, however, it doesn't work on the server (`snmpwalk -v2c client_ip -c abc123`) and got timeout error, and the TCPDUMP from the client at the same time shows following messages:

```
tcpdump: listening on ens18, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:30:02.776848 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 3288, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
13:30:03.778174 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 3435, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
13:30:04.779138 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 3619, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
13:30:05.780377 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 3811, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
13:30:06.781420 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 3817, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
13:30:07.782405 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 4065, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    snmp_server.60035 > snmp_client.snmp: [udp sum ok]  { SNMPv2c C="abc123" { GetNextRequest(25) R=404279833   } }
```

UDP161 is wide open and the server can connect to this port as well.

Packaged installed on the client:

```
# dpkg -l|grep snmp
ii  libsnmp-base                    5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2         all          SNMP configuration script, MIBs and documentation
ii  libsnmp30:amd64                 5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2         amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
ii  snmp                            5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2         amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) applications
ii  snmpd                           5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2         amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) agents
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ss -ua` to the question.

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the advice! The Netfilter was blocking SNMP and it works after I manually allow 161 for communication! If you can put your reply in the answer section I can close this case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 10 may actually be using the newer Netfilter instead of iptables. Does `nft list ruleset` report anything other than empty filter chains?

Do `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow` have any restrictions defined that would be applicable to snmpd?